# How are the ranges of these cdf determined?

Tags: cumulative-distribution-functions

[image]

In the solution, it says $a > 0$ is $P(aX+b\leq y)$ and $a < 0$ is $P(aX+b\geq y)$. Can I get an explanation for why that is, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because, when you divide by a, the inequality will change sign, so you get for a<0 : $$P(aX+b\leq y)=P\left(X\geq\frac{y-b}{a}\right)=1-F_X\left(\frac{y-b}{a}\right) $$

Comment: Does it only change sign when $a<0$?

Comment: Yes. If a>0 then aX> Y is equivalent to X> Y/a but    if a< 0 then aX> Y is equivalent to X< Y/a.   Notice that while 5> 4, -5< -4.

Comment: I think there was a typo

Answer (score 0):

Let $Y=aX+b$, where $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ with $a\ne 0$.

By definition, 
$$
F_Y(y)=P(Y\le y)=P(aX+b\le y)
\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\;\;\;\;\;
$$
hence if $a > 0$ we get
\begin{align*}
F_Y(y)
&=\,
P(aX+b\le y)
\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\;\;\;
\\[4pt]
&=\,
P(aX\le y-b)
\\[4pt]
&=\,
P\Bigl(X\le \frac{y-b}{a}\Bigr)
\\[4pt]
&=\,
F_X\Bigl(\frac{y-b}{a}\Bigr)
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
and if $a < 0$, correcting a typo in the referenced solution, we get
\begin{align*}
F_Y(y)
&=\,
P(aX+b\le y)
\\[4pt]
&=\,
1-P(aX+b\ge y)&&\text{[assuming $P(aX+b=y)=0$]}
\\[4pt]
&=\,
1-P(aX\ge y-b)
\\[4pt]
&=\,
1-P\Bigl(X\le \frac{y-b}{a}\Bigr)&&\text{[since $a < 0$, dividing by $a$}\\[-4pt] 
&&&\;\text{reverses the direction of the inequality]}
\\[4pt]
&=\,
1-F_X\Bigl(\frac{y-b}{a}\Bigr)
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}